# Find coefficients for trigonometric function by points and derivatives

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I have two points $p_1=(x_1, y_1)$ and $p_2=(x_2, y_2)$. I also have the derivative values at the same x values: $\dot{p}_1=(x_1, \dot{y}_1)$ and $\dot{p}_2=(x_2, \dot{y}_2)$; $\ddot{p}_1=(x_1, \ddot{y}_1)$ and $\ddot{p}_2=(x_2, \ddot{y}_2)$; $\dddot{p}_1=(x_1, \dddot{y}_1)$ and $\dddot{p}_2=(x_2, \dddot{y}_2)$ up to the third derivative.

Is there a posibility to get the coefficients for the sinus:
$$
f(x) = a\sin(bx + c) + d
$$
What I need is $a, b, c$ and $d$.

What I tried: Similar to the polynomial problem I started with the derivatives of $f$:
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = ab\cos(bx + c)
$$
$$
\frac{d^2f}{dx} = -ab^2\sin(bx + c)
$$
$$
\frac{d^3f}{dx} = -ab^3\cos(bx + c)
$$
From there I'm stuck. I tried some of the [trigonometric rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) but could not isolate the coeficients.

It would be really nice if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks for any help,
Peter

Comment: You have four equations, and eight constraints, which seems kind of odd. Anyway, I would focus first on finding the value of $d$, because it can only be inferred from $p_1$ and $p_2$ and the equation for $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in general has no solution.

Why? You can, for each of $x_1$ and $x_2$, compute $y'''/y'$ from your data, and you know that this should equal

$$
f'''(x_i) / f'(x_i) = \frac{-ab^3 \sin(bx_i + c)}{ ab\sin(bx_i + c)} = b^2.
$$

Note that this means that if $y'''/y'$ at either $x_1$ or $x_2$ is negative, you cannot find coefficient to make this function fit.

It also means that $y'''/y'$ must be the *same* at both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Short summary: the class of functions you're trying to fit to your data is not as rich of the class of data you're providing.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought it would be necessary to provide the second and third derivate for each point. But I think for my application it would be sufficient to set them as zero. In this case I can calculate the coefficients.